# Swift: How to make this function generic

Tags: swift, generics

Here is what I have:

```
class func truncateTailsOfRange(range: Range<Int>, portion: Double) -> Range<Int> {
    let start = range.startIndex + Int(portion * Double(range.count))
    let end = range.endIndex - Int(portion * Double(range.count))
    return Range(start: start, end: end)
}
```

I would like to make this generic for IntegerType:

```
class func truncateTailsOfRange<T: IntegerType>(range: Range<T>, portion: Double) -> Range<T> {
    let start = range.startIndex + T(portion * Double(range.count))
    let end = range.endIndex - T(portion * Double(range.count))
    return Range(start: start, end: end)
}
```

But the error I get is:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type `Double` with an argument list of type (`T.Distance`)

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you need a range for all integer types? It would be much easier to create a method for each one you need.

Comment: I only need Int, but the motivation was simply that there is no reason to restrict this to ints

Comment: You're trying to invoke a constructor on T, but T is not an actual class/struct/enum but rather just a "type."

Answer (score 0):

First you need a `CustomDoubleConvertible` protocol. This mirrors `CustomStringConvertible`. You extend all Types which you want to be convertible to `Double`. Similar to `description` which returns a `String` representation of a Type.

```
protocol CustomDoubleConvertible {

    var doubleValue : Double { get }
}

extension Int : CustomDoubleConvertible {

    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }

}

extension Int16 : CustomDoubleConvertible {

    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }

}
```

If you make the function an extension to `Range` itself you can make use of it's generic nature and it's `typealiases`.

```
extension Range where Element.Distance : CustomDoubleConvertible {
```

Now you can calculate the offsets of the indexes like so :

```
let startOffset = Int(portion * self.count.doubleValue)
let endOffset = Int(portion * self.count.doubleValue)
```

If you further constrain `Range` so that it's `Element` must be a `BidirectionalIndexType` you can use `successor` and `predecessor`.

```
extension Range where Element.Distance : CustomDoubleConvertible, Element : BidirectionalIndexType {
```

This allows you to get the full function by iterating over the offsets and calling `successor` and `predecessor`.

```
extension Range where Element.Distance : CustomDoubleConvertible, Element : BidirectionalIndexType {

    func truncateTailsOfRange(portion: Double) -> Range<Element> {

        let startOffset = Int(portion * self.count.doubleValue)
        let endOffset = Int(portion * self.count.doubleValue)

        var start = self.startIndex
        var end = self.endIndex

        for _ in 0..<startOffset { start = start.successor() }
        for _ in 0..<endOffset { end = end.predecessor() }

        return Range(start: start, end: end)
    }
}
```

Some tests :

```
let rangeA = 1...4 // 1..<5

let rangeB = "a"..."g"

rangeA.truncateTailsOfRange(0.3) // 2..<4

rangeB.truncateTailsOfRange(0.3) // has no member ....



let w : Int16 = 3
let z : Int16 = 9

let rangeC = w...z // 3..<10
rangeC.truncateTailsOfRange(0.4) // 5..<8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting but academic exercise.

Here's a method that is not very efficient but that will work with all range types:

```
 func truncateTailsOfRange<T>(var range: Range<T>, portion: Double) -> Range<T> 
 {
     let elementCount    = Array(range).count
     let truncationCount = Int( portion * Double(elementCount) ) 
     let remainingCount  = max(0, elementCount - 2 * truncationCount)

     for _ in 0..<truncationCount 
     { range.startIndex = range.startIndex.successor() }

     range.endIndex = range.startIndex

     for _ in 0..<remainingCount
     { range.endIndex = range.endIndex.successor() }

     return range
 }
```

and here's a much quicker one :

```
 func truncateTailsOfRange2<T>(var range: Range<T>, portion: Double) -> Range<T> 
 {
     if range.isEmpty {return range}
     let elements = Array(range)
     let truncationCount = Int( portion * Double(elements.count) )
     let remainingCount  = max(0, elements.count - 2 * truncationCount)
     return elements[truncationCount]..<elements[truncationCount+remainingCount]
 }
```